# Implementation of the bounded-distance decoder of Leech-lattice?

Tags: lattices, quantization

Hi all,

I am wondering, anybody can help me how can I find an implemented version of Leech-Lattice quantizer/decoder, i.e., "Matlab", "C++" or "Python" code, using the approach proposed by Ofer Amrani and Yair Be'ery in "The Leech Lattice and the Golay code: Bounded-Distance decoding and multilevel construction" or "Efficient bounded-distance decoding of the Hexacode and associated decoders for the leech lattice and the Golay code" papers.

Best regards,

Farzad

Comment: Have they found something better for the Golay code than the tailbiting trellis of Forney et al? Have you asked them directly? I'm sad to say I didn't know about this paper (even though I refereed Amrani & Be'ery paper on multilevel construction of RM-codes). Probably need to start working seriously again :-)

Answer (score 1):

May need more testing, but here's what I got. looked for a long time, so i tried to implement it myself.
https://github.com/leecarraher/GPULSHImage/blob/master/leechDecoder.c